# In Google Analytics report, Visits are coming but no data for PageViews are coming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-analytics

i have incorporated the google analytics in my iphn application. When i am checking my reports, data for Visits are coming but no data for PageViews and Pages/Visit are coming.
in my appDelegate file inside the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method i have pasted this code as well-

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"UA-20206851-1"
                  dispatchPeriod:10
  delegate:nil];
```

i am using this code for pageView tracking in my viewDidLoad method-

```
NSError *error;
if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"BuildsViewController.xib" withError:&error]) 
{
// Handle error here
}
```

even for event tracking no data is coming. i am using this code for that-

```
NSError *error;
if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"ButtonClicked"
action:@"production1"
label:@"Environment1"
value:-1
withError:&error])
{
// Handle error here
}
```

here "trackEvent" is method name and i have used any string in "action" and "label".
please tell why PageViews are not coming

Comment: It means your Google Analytics implementation is connecting (since the events are coming through, and account for why you see visits at all), but there must be something wrong with the trackPageview call. I don't know Objective-C or iPhone programming, so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Only way way to see visits but not pageViews and other metrics or reports is if you aren't waiting long enough for the data to come in.  GA takes up to 24 hours to have all the data show up in reports.  Don't trust any numbers before at least 24 hours have past.

Comment: its been 48hours now. Visits are increasing in every 24hours but still pageViews are zero(0).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a slash: `trackPageview:@"/BuildsViewController.xib"`
Don't about the dots :)

I've read that google will go crazy for a day when it gets pageview name without a slash.

Comment: I suspect the same, but I couldn't find supporting evidence. I went to the analytics forum for help: http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/analytics/wjxHzNcQjdo/discussion